# Freeing memory and closing sem_t in a function?

Tags: c, function, semaphore, shared-memory

I have created a semaphore and some shared memory in my program that at the end of the program, I'm going to close like this:

```
sem_close();
sem_unlink();

shmdt();
shmctl();
```

However, if something goes wrong during the program and it needs to exit, I need to free those resources sooner, so I wanted to write a function like this:

```
void f( sem_t *s, int *shm, int shmid ) {

sem_close(s);
sem_unlink(name);

shmdt(shm);
shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

}
```

Where name is the name of my sempahore defined above the program.

However I am getting the "conflicting types" error pop up.

Is there a way to free the resources via a function like this before the program ends?

I'd be glad for any help! Thanks!

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why exactly do you feel the need to mix SysV and POSIX semaphores?

Comment: @Daeto, you didn't mix SysV and POSIX semaphores as far as I can tell, but you *did* mix POSIX semaphores and SysV shared memory segments.  One would normally choose one or the other set of IPC mechanisms, not mix and match.

Comment: In any event, heed Joachim's comment.  The answer to the question as you have posed it is simply "Yes."  You have not given us enough information to say much more than that even if we wanted to do.

Comment: The only thing I wanna do is to free all the resources (close semaphores and free the memory) from inside a function and I can't figure out how to declate the function properly.